# How to change my Default internet connection

Tags: network-manager, network-bridge

I'm having two ethernet ports in my system and i'm using one for my internet connection another one for file sharing i'm using eno1 for internet and eno2 for my file sharing. but my system automatically takes eno2 as my default connection so i cant able to use both internet and file sharing simultaneously.

I have attached the screen shot of the connection information with this mail.[image]

I want to make BSNL as my default connection and AMRF as my secondary connection